# Por que "professora" pode significar ’prostituta que inicia adolescentes’?

Tags: significado, etimologia, origem-histórica

Se você fizer uma pesquisa no Google com a expressão "significado de professora", vai aparecer:

[image]

De acordo com a matéria que pode ser visualizada [neste link](https://extra.globo.com/noticias/brasil/pesquisa-do-google-define-professora-como-prostituta-classifica-como-brasileirismo-24032838.html), "o mesmo resultado aparece em outros dicionários, como o Houaiss, e no dicio.com.br". Quando a mesma busca é feita por "professor", o resultado é diferente. Neste caso, o primeiro resultado diz "aquele que professa uma crença"; e o segundo, "aquele que ensina".

Por que existe esse sentido de "prostituta" para professora?

Comment: Viva! Quem é vivo sempre aparece :) Não sei como demonstrar o porquê desse sentido, mas parece-me que resulta de a sociedade tradicional ver com bons olhos a iniciação sexual de rapazes solteiros e ainda adolescentes, mas reprovar a atividade sexual de moças solteiras. Em tempos, em certas regiões de Portugal era comum levar um rapaz a uma prostituta antes de ele ingressar nas forças armadas; em certas zonas havia até um nome para isso, a *desobriga*. Não seria nada de surpreendente chamar a essa prostituta *professora*. >>

Comment: De um modo gera, especialmente no passado, considerava-se que uma mulher adulta que tivesse relações com um rapaz virgem estaria a prestar-lhe um serviço; um homem que fizesse o mesmo com uma moça virgem, estaria a abusar dela.

Comment: @Jacinto Viva! Estou por aí :). Acho que tem mesmo haver com essa cultura do passado, mas estaria a definição ultrapassada então?

Comment: Imagino que esteja. Duvido que haja ainda muitos adolescentes a recorrer a prostitutas para se iniciarem sexualmente hoje em dia. Naturalmente, uma definição pode estar ultrapassada na comunicação atual, mas continua a existir na literatura produzida no passado. O Houaiss diz que esse sentido de *professora* é do Nordeste brasileiro.

Comment: Denis, tomei talvez liberdade excessiva ao editar o teu título. Vê se gostas; se não gostares só tens de fazer rollback :)

Comment: O novo título ficou ótimo.

Comment: Rolou uma polêmica. [Após protestos, Google tira do ar definição que associava 'professora' a 'prostituta'](https://t.co/QY749AC6xP)

Comment: Parece-me que, junto com a dedução do Jacinto, isto seria suficiente para construir uma boa resposta: «Em relação à palavra 'professora', a Oxford University Press, nossa parceira que trabalha com tradicionais editores de dicionário no Brasil, determinou que a segunda definição está em desuso e não é atual o bastante para ser incluída.» Eu não tenho vagar para isso, agora. :p

Comment: Sim, também acho que dá para elaborar uma boa resposta. Será bom deixar isso registrado aqui.

Comment: @Jacinto essa resposta saí? :)

Comment: @JorgeB., vamos a ver. Não tenho de responder a tudo. Se mais ninguém responder, provavelmente acabarei por fazer uma resposta. Mas neste momento não tenho a informação que desejaria para uma boa resposta.

Comment: De onde saiu isso? rs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse significado é um regionalismo, uma gíria; por sinal, muito incomum para o significado de "professora".

A palavra "prostituta", assim como as palavras que se referem aos órgãos sexuais, possuem uma infinidade de termos com o mesmo significado, sem que se perca ou se descaracterize o significado originário da palavra.

Assim, também pode significar "prostituta" a palavra "prima", sem que isso faça que a palavra "prima" seja imediatamente identificada como prostituta ou faça com que seu uso seja restrito ou mal visto de qualquer maneira, quando usada na forma original.

Da mesma forma, poder-se-ia dizer que as prostitutas atuam como professoras na arte do sexo para jovens inexperientes, mas esse uso é muito incomum ou mesmo desconhecido entre a maioria dos falantes de português.

Pode-se citar de forma análoga o uso da palavra "linguiça" para o órgão sexual masculino; ainda que esse uso seja relativamente comum, isso não faz com que imediatamente se atribua esse significado ao lermos a palavra "linguiça", que, em 99% das vezes, realmente significa o alimento com o qual se faz churrasco.

Comment: Muito boa resposta.  Eu estava a escrever um comentário mas achei desnecessário.  Tu dizes tudo aqui.  Em tempo:  sem ser em contexto, eu não entenderia esse significado da palavra professora, que acredito ser um regionalismo.